# Getting error in java mail api PasswordAuthentication method

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send mail using java mail api..Every thing is ok in the code except the Authenticator class .It is giving warning as ...

```
Constructor PasswordAuthentication can not be applied to given types.
required java.lang.String,java.lang.char[]
```

Here is my code snippet where i am getting warning error but not able to resolve the issue...

```
Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {

        @Override
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
 error           return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password);
        }
    };
      error   Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);
```

These two lines with //error is giving error in the code..

Please help me.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: What's the type of userName and password ?

Comment: @ZouZou final String userName, final String password

Comment: If you are using `getPassword` note it returns a `char[]`, not a `String`. You can convert it via `new String(char[])`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<del>[`PasswordAuthentication`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/PasswordAuthentication.html#PasswordAuthentication%28java.lang.String,%20char%5B%5D%29) constructor only accept a `String` and a `char` array as arguments. So you should do :</del>

<del>`return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password.toCharArray());`</del>

**Edit :**

The problem is that [`Session.getInstance(java.util.Properties props, Authenticator authenticator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Session.html#getInstance%28java.util.Properties,%20javax.mail.Authenticator%29)  requires an `Authentificator` object from the `javax.mail` package.

I think you've imported the wrong package. It should be `javax.mail.Authenticator` and not `java.net.Authenticator`

So you should use the object `PasswordAuthentication` from the `javax.mail` package (which accept two `Strings` as argument), instead of the object `PasswordAuthentification` from the `java.net` package (which accept a `String` and a `char` array).

Comment: i am also getting error on this line Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);

Answer (score 1):

when you call the constructor `PasswordAuthentication(String a, char[] b)`

the Exception is telling you that you are passing a wrong type in the parameters, for example:

your code: `return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password);`

userName or password are wrong type, maybe userName is not a String or password is not a char[], take a look carefully.

Comment: sir i am getting error on this line also Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);

Comment: is same exception? parameter auth is an object of passwordAuthentication too?

Comment: error is no suitable method found for getinstance on line Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);

Comment: Most likely you're still importing the wrong Authenticator.  Note that [you don't need to use an Authenticator at all](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Session session = Session.getInstance(properties,
          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
          });
```

Comment: I tried this, but I still get the same error :-( which is weird since this looks like the perfect answer to force it to be of javax.mail.auth type

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gmail account, you must disable the two step authentication or you can either set on your gmail account app password and use the app password instead in your application.

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en